# WebRTC / RTCPeerConnection: Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_SENTACCEPT

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm implementing a webcam chat. I am getting this error `Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_SENTACCEPT`.

The user that gets it has an `RTCPeerConnection` open that waits for an SDP offer from another user, before executing this code where the error occures:

```
function receiveOffer(offer)
{
    offer = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(offer));
    remotePc; // defined somewhere else

    remotePc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() 
    {
        remotePc.createAnswer(function(answer) 
        {
            remotePc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer), function() 
            {
                // send answer
            },error); 
        },error);
    },error);
}
```

The line that throws the error is `setLocalDescription`. In general, does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Is `remotePc` also making an offer somewhere else in the code?

Comment: It doesn't make offers, but apparently sometimes it gets ice candidates of the remote peer before it gets an offer. I'm trying to find out if that could be an issue.

Comment: It is, you cannot set any ice candidates until remoteSDP is set. If you try to, there will be problems. I would skip ice trickling altogether and do not send your offer sdp until all the candidates are set.

Comment: Phewww. Thanks for your comment. Let me just wrap my head around that. :)

Comment: So far I got my ice candidates automatically by passing the ice servers in the constructor of the PeerConnection. Am I correctly assuming that `updateIce` gets me my ice candidates too? I'll try that.

Comment: There is now a flag for `RTCPeerConnection` called `oniceconnectionstatechange`. You can have your own function for its callback and when the state is `complete` send your localDesc. So, create an offer, do not send it until you have an ice state of complete.

Comment: In my case , Problem was in my code , offer was being created from both the side.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent can you post code how would you do that, because I tried putting all remote ice candidates in an array and tried adding them if `completed` status. event never fired, however, normally it was.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411465/why-webrtc-is-giving-error-failed-to-set-remote-answer-sdp-called-in-wrong-st

Comment: nvm i dont think this is the porblem